# Elixir getting values that are not empty in a map

Tags: dictionary, enums, elixir

Given a map like this:

`mapOne = %{"dog" => "foo", "cat" => "", "name" => "generic","fizz" => "", }`

How would you get just the keys of the values which are empty into a list?
`["cat", "fizz"]`

It seems that `Enum.filter` is returning a list of key, value pairs rather than just the list

`mapOne |> Enum.filter(fn {k,v} -> if v == "" do k end end)
[{"cat", ""}, {"fizz", ""}]`

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Comprehensions work well for this case:

```
iex(1)> mapOne = %{"dog" => "foo", "cat" => "", "name" => "generic","fizz" => "", }

iex(2)> for {k, v} <- mapOne, v == "", do: k

["cat", "fizz"]
```

Comment: Great answer! I haven't got used to the for loop in elixir yet.

Comment: Thank you! Haven't gotten used to the for loop syntax in elixir as well.

Answer (score 1):

```
Enum.reduce(mapOne, [], fn
  ({k, ""}, acc) -> [k | acc]
  ({k, _v}, acc) -> acc
end)
```

This returns a list with reversed order than the previous answer, but the key order of a map means nothing anyway.

Answer (score 0):

```
mapOne = %{"dog" => "foo", "cat" => "", "name" => "generic","fizz" => "", }

mapOne
|> Enum.filter(fn{_k, v}-> v == "" end)
|> Enum.map(fn{k, _v}-> k end)
```

By the way, `Enum.filter/2` takes **the items in the original list/map** that make the anonymous function return **truthy value** (i.e. not `false` and not `nil`).

Your anonymous function

```
fn {k,v} -> if v == "" do k end end
```

returns `nil` (which is falsey) when `v` is not empty, and `k` (which is a string thus always truthy) when `v` is empty.